# How to generate the dynamic angular form with the JSON data conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am new at Angular and trying to make dynamic forms with JSON data. The conditions should be selected from the options type selection from the JSON data. I have tried the following code but it does not work

```
<mat-card class="rahmendaten-container">
  <h3 class="page__header">{{stepCfg.stepHeading}}</h3>
  <div *ngIf="!!stepCfg.htmlContent" [innerHTML]="stepCfg.htmlContent"> 
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-card-content class="page">
      <div class="page__container">
        <div *ngFor="let prop of formTemplate" class="container__row">
          <div [ngSwitch]="prop.type">
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
              <span [innerHTML]="prop.label" 
              class="container__row__label"></span>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select [formControlName]="onChange($event,prop)" 
                [formControlName]="values[prop.label + i]">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of prop.options" 
                  [value]="option.value">{{option.label}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Type script

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    form:FormGroup;
    array: any[] = [];
    selectItems: any;
    formTemplate:any = form_template;
    stepCfg = {
      stepType: 'rahmendaten',
      stepHeading: '',
      stepIndex: 0,
      steps: [],
      firstStep: false,
      lastStep: false,
      onlyStep: false,
      data: {},
      htmlContent: ''
    };
    formDataObj = {};

  constructor() {}   

  ngOnInit() {
    for (const prop of Object.keys(this.stepCfg.data)) {
      this.formDataObj[prop] = new 
      FormControl(this.stepCfg.data[prop].value);
      this.formTemplate.push({
        key: prop,
        label: this.stepCfg.data[prop].label,
        type: this.stepCfg.data[prop].type,
        options: this.stepCfg.data[prop].options
      });
   }
   this.form = new FormGroup(this.formDataObj);
  }

  onChange(evt) {

    this.formTemplate.forEach(prop => {
      let options = prop.options.filter(x => x.value == evt)[0]
      var allLabels: string[] = this.formTemplate.map(x => x.label)

      if (options) {
        if (options.subfield && 
        !allLabels.includes(options.subfield.label)) {
          let obj = { ...options.subfield }
          this.formTemplate.push(obj)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}

 const form_template = [{
  "type": "select",
  "label": "Test1",
  "options": [
  {
      "value": "sped1",
      "label": "A Test GmbH",
      "subfield": {
        "type": "select",
        "label": "Subfield1",
        "options": [
          {
            "value": "subfieldvalue1",
            "label": "101"
          },
          {
            "value": "subfieldvalue1",
            "label": "101"
          },
        ]
       }
  },
  {
      "value": "sped2",
      "label": "Test2 GmbH"
  },
  {
     "value": "sped3",
     "label": "test3"
  },
  ]
}
```

]
   export default form_template

After getting the valueable help from @AdritaSharma; I havr tried this but it do not work.

Comment: And what have your tried, and where are you facing an issue?

Comment: Have you went through the modified solution?

Comment: @AdritaSharma Thank you so much this is what i wants but can you please help me to remove this error. ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(46,15): error TS2339: Property 'isChild' does not exist on type '{ "type": string; "label": string; "options": { "value": string; "label": string; }[]; }'.

Comment: isChild property has to be included in the hain.. try adding it, I will modify the demo at morning.

Comment: Check the modified demo.

Comment: I think you have missed`  `"isChild" : true`, that I added in `subfield`

Comment: `        "subfield": {
          "type": "select",
          "label": "Subfield1",
          "isChild" : true,
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "subfieldvalue1",
              "label": "101"
            },
          ]
        }`

Comment: Thank You @AdritaSharma But we can not change the JSON Data there is already predefined data.

Comment: Ok. Use `Object.assign(options.subfield, {isChild:true});`

Comment: Check modified demo

Comment: Have you checked the modified one?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but after your suggestion i try to work for my requirement and it do not work, I have updated what, I have tried in the question section, please look on it. @AdritaSharma

Comment: You shouldn't modify the question 2 days after it was asked and already has an answer based on the previous version of the question. You could have asked a new question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987457/angular-dynamic-form-view-from-json-data-with-nested-condition/57987981#57987981 @AdritaSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of form_template">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.type">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
      {{item.label}}
            <select>
               <option *ngFor="let option of item.options" [value]="option.sped1">
                   {{option.label}}
               </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-287krj)

To accomodate **Subfield** I made few changes:

**[Working Demo with Subfield](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkcd66?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of form_template">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="item.type">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'select'">
            {{item.label}}
            <select (ngModelChange)="onChange($event,item.isChild)" [(ngModel)]="values[item.label + i]">
        <option *ngFor="let option of item.options" [value]="option.value">
          {{option.label}}
        </option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Typescript:

```
 onChange(evt, isChild?) {

    this.form_template.forEach(item => {
      let options = item.options.filter(x => x.value == evt)[0]
      var allLabels: string[] = this.form_template.map(x => x.label)

      if (options) {

        if (options.subfield && !allLabels.includes(options.subfield.label)) {
          Object.assign(options.subfield, {isChild:true});
          this.form_template.push(options.subfield)
        }
      } else {
        this.form_template.forEach((x, i) => {
          x.options.forEach(y => {
            if (y.value != evt) {

              this.form_template.forEach((item, itemIndex) => {

                if (item.options.indexOf(y)) {
                  if (!isChild) {
                    this.form_template.splice(itemIndex, 1)
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Adrita sharma I have worked as you told but the problem is after selecting parent options from drop down the sub field content should be appear on the form such as in this cas after selecting the the first element Adrian Speditions GmbH from drop down the child content of this elements "label": "Subfield1", and another drop down options should be appear on the form.

Comment: @Learner I made some changes for subfield, go through the demo and let me know if you are unable to understand any part.

Answer (score 1):

Well simply put it might be possible but it is more time consuming than traditional methods. If you do that several things come into play like design, error messages etc it will become complicated than what you have in hand. I also had this idea (inspired by.net MVC) but it's not worth it.